# Mapped Memory CreatViewSource not reading memory written

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I have a task thread that runs continuous loop and performs read using mapped memory file.
When from another application information writes information to the mapped memory file the loop in the other application running the task read only retrieves that information on a using win32 mapped memory file methods are used and not c# native memory mapped file methods.

For example here is the code using win32 mapped memory file methods in a task thread and this works. When the information is written to the mapped memory file from another application the Marchal.Copy in the task thread method retrieves information

```
 IntPtr 
     _iFileMappingHandle,
     _iFileMapStartAddress;

            _iFileMappingHandle = Win32.CreateFileMapping(Win32.InvalidFileHandle, 0,
                                                 Win32.FileProtection.ReadWrite,
                                                 0, (uint)Size, Name);
            _iFileMapStartAddress = Win32.MapViewOfFile(_iFileMappingHandle,
                                                       Win32.FileRights.ReadWrite, 0, 0, 0);
 var autoReset = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset, LockName);
 if (autoReset.WaitOne(5000))
 {
     byte[] bTemp = new byte[Size];
    
    Marshal.Copy(_iFileMapStartAddress, bTemp, 0, 512);
```

But if use the c# memory mapped file methods shown below is used in the same task thread the Read method never retrieves the information written to mapped memory file from the other application.
Any suggestion on how to Read method to work? If needed leave me and email address I can post a demo code on github for download, or email the source code if you like.

```
 var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(Name
                  , Size
                  , MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);

 var viewSteam = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, Size);
  var autoReset = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset, LockName);
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    if (autoReset.WaitOne(5000))
    {
        byte[] bTemp = new byte[Size];
        viewSteam.Read(bTemp, 0, Size);
```

Comment: [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.read?view=net-8.0#system-io-unmanagedmemorystream-read(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32)) returns number of bytes were read, is it zero or non-zero in this case?

Comment: One auto-reset even doesn't seem like it will be enough to coordinate this.

Comment: Auto reset work fine. If the autoreset did now work find the read method would never be called

Comment: The read method is always returning no bytes

Comment: This ticket can be closed.  I found code that uses pretty much the same format as code as the Win32 involving Marshalling and the SafeMemoryMappedViewhandle.  As far as all those Microsoft example and rofl  all the people who post examples and videos, the are all pretty much worthless and never would be used in the production. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956167/how-can-i-quickly-read-bytes-from-a-memory-mapped-file-in-net

Comment: Well it seems using the MemoryMappedViewAccessor WriteArray<T> and ReadArray<T> method work. Both these methods it states is UnmanagedMemoryAccessor. So the question is do I have use these in an unsafe method? When testing with these two methods in a method that was not marked as unsage it worked? I guess maybe that is another question to post.